# why my service starts after ondestroy of activity which was started by this service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-activity

Today I found the strange problem.In my application I am starting a activity from service

```
Intent in=new Intent(AlarmService.this, GuardActivity.class);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(in);
```

Now after sometime i call ondestroy of activity. here I observe that my service is started again.
This behavior is very strange.Do any body faced same problem

It is simple services with just above line...So I am not posting complete code

Activity

```
       Timer t = new Timer();
       t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

              @Override
              public void run() {

                     try{
                         finish();//Activity destroy itself after 10 sec
                     }
                     catch(Exception e)
                     {

                     }
                   }
       }, 10*1000);// 10 sec
```

Comment: Why would you need to call `onDestroy()` manually? Looks like a very bad idea...

Comment: no actully my activity is destroyed itself after 10 sec

Comment: When you activity finished it will be called `onDestroy()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting on answer because of I can't comment,
had you stoped service by calling `stopself();` 
after

```
Intent in=new Intent(AlarmService.this, GuardActivity.class);
in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(in);
```

Comment: after observing this problem I am doing same wat u sugested it solved my problem but ques remained as it is ..Why it is happening

Comment: because by finishing the activity only activity stops not service,we need to stop service either by calling 'stopSelf();' within service or have to stop service from activity by calling stopService(Intent)

Comment: if service is running no problem but it is calling onStartCommand once again after activity is finished..that is issue

Comment: what are you returning from onStartCommand() method of service?if you are returning START_NOT_STICKY then change it to START_STICKY.

Comment: thanks for giving ur precious time but my service is a normal service not like START_NOT_STICKY

Comment: can you tell me what is version of your device?