# Service Starts Again After Destory An Acticity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have observed a very strange thing while working on my project I think is a duplicate question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730597/why-my-service-starts-after-ondestroy-of-activity-which-was-started-by-this-serv) but I didn't find an appropriate solution. I'm working an android application in which I have created a background service. The problem I'm facing is when I destroy an activity which starts a service. Its run the service again (n show a notification) I don't know why. I don't know where I went wrong. Could anyone please go thru the snippet and sort out the problem. 
thanks in Advance. YOUR help should be appreciated.

**Acitivty:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_option_selection);

    cm = new ConnectionManager(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent = cm.isConnected();

    serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
//      serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

//  isMyServiceRunning();
    if(!isMyServiceRunning())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no service running, starting service..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
}

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    isMyServiceRunning();
    if(!isMyServiceRunning())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no service running, starting service..",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        String temp = service.service.getClassName();
        if ("com.smartclasss.alerts.MyService".equals(temp)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**SERVICE:**

```
public class MyService extends Service{
   @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    time = new Timer();
    time.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            final String currentDate = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());         
            if(flag == false)
            {
                try {
                    savingDateinPref(currentDate);          
                    new DoInBackground().execute(currentDate);  
                    flag = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            String val = prefs.getString("TAG_KEY", "defValue");
            if(!currentDate.equals(val))
            {
            flag = false;
            prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE); 
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 

            editor.remove("TAG_KEY");
             //---saves the values--- 
             editor.commit(); 

            }
        }
    },0,5000);
return START_STICKY;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you are starting your service in `onPause` and never stop it

Comment: I dont want to stop my service. so that's why I didnt call stopService method

Comment: When you are destroying your Activity it first goes to onPause and the Toast gets shown. Why do you start it onPause you already did so in onCreate

Comment: I have tried this, but it didn't work. destroying an activity means clean the process with sweeping it from your cellphone.